# Drawable blurred on some devices

Tags: android, image, drawable

This refresh drawable is blurred on some devices, e.g. Galaxy Tab 10.1N (Android 3.2).
No problems on my Nexus 7 (Android 4.4).

[image][image]

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/buttonrefresh"
    android:layout_width="52dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_button_background"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"/>
```

ic_action_refresh is located in res/drawable_xxhdpi and has the size of 96x96 pixels.
What could be the reason?

Answer (score 6):

Becuse galaxy tab 10.1 is not XXHDPI, it's probably MDPI (but i don't know), so Android system is scaling this big resource to MDPI and with scaling quality is lost. You should scale resources on your own and use few resource folders for many screen dpi's (`drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`... and so on)

Comment: Are you sure? If you scale down an image there is no blur... I don't want to create additional 150 images x 3 sizes x 2 colors = 900 images...

Comment: I'm sure that this is scaling problem. Because system automatically scale bigger resources to target density.
If you scale down it on your own in PhotoShop or other program it will be fine. But Android system is using fast scaling which may be not so accurrate and it may be quality loss

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to want to add appropriate drawable resources for mdpi, hdpi, and xhdpi in addition to xxhdpi. This will allow the OS to choose the correct drawable resource based on the pixel density of each device's screen.